# How can I load an image in lightning without including the namespace?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources, namespace

I'm trying to include an image that I loaded as a static resource in a Lightning component. The image doesn't show up if I don't include my namespace. For example, this won't work:

> <img src="/resource/FFPsa" />

However, if I include my namespace, it will:

> <img src="/resource/abehrmandev210__FFPsa" />

How can I use the image without using my namespace?

For those not doing managed development, wouldn't this also cause issues with static resource caching? URLFOR in visualforce adds a cache buster to the path to prevent stale data, but it seems lightning has so such facility. Is this right?

Comment: From the docs ,there is no official way to do this yet .For managed package you will need to include a namespace for your component

Answer (score 5):

This has been solved with [Summer 16 release](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm) now .

```
<aura:component>
<!-- Stand-alone static resources -->
<img src="{!$Resource.generic_profile_svg}"/>
<img src="{!$Resource.yourNamespace__generic_profile_svg}"/>

<!-- Asset from an archive static resource -->
<img src="{!$Resource.SLDSv1 + '/assets/images/avatar1.jpg'}"/>
<img src="{!$Resource.yourNamespace__SLDSv1 + '/assets/images/avatar1.jpg'}"/>
```